# Initializa Bean with YAML configuration in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I would like to read some properties, like DB access configs, when initializing bean or service in spring boot.

Anyone knows good ways ?

This is my current code snippet.

```
public class SampleApplication implements ApplicationRunner
{
    @Autowired
    private YAMLConfig myConfig;

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println(myConfig != null); //YAMLConfig has been intialized here
    }

    public SampleApplication()
    {
        System.out.println(myConfig == null); //myConfig is null
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class Config
    {
        @Bean
        @ConditionalOnProperty(value = {"batch.execute"}, havingValue = "SampleApplication")
        public SampleApplication sampleApplication()
        {
            return new SampleApplication();
        }
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties
public class YAMLConfig
{
    private String environment;

    public String getEnvironment()
    {
        return environment;
    }

    public void setEnvironment(String environment)
    {
        this.environment = environment;
    }
}
```

Thanks for taking a look at this!

Comment: there is no right answer for this. Whatever suits your needs. the way you are doing with `@ConfigurationProperties` is pretty good. You can do the same for your Db Access configs also. If you show the yml, may be we can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create this method inside your `SampleApplication` class

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    // at this point, all the dependency injection has happened already
    myConfig.doStuff()
}
```

it will be called by spring automatically after all bean initialization has been done.